# combine portions of two arrays together

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a script that tests whether a service is running or not, I'm making some adjustments to it and have gotten a little stuck. Originally the script had one array that it ran over based on data provided in the url. It looks like:

```
$request = array(
    "pe" => $_REQUEST['number'],
    "key" => "1234",
    "City" => "San Antonio", // This will be overwritten by data from the states array
    "State" => "Texas", // This will be overwritten by data from the states array
    "fname" => "John",
    "lname" => "Doe",
    "ZipCode" => "78201", // This will be overwritten by data from the states array
    "Email" => "jdoe@email.com",
    "Phone" => "2225550000",
);
```

I have a second array (multidimensional) which looks like:

```
$states = array(
    "California" => array(
        "abbr" => "CA",
        "city" => "Sacramento",
        "zip" => "95632"
    ),
    "Washington" => array(
        "abbr" => "WA",
        "city" => "Seattle",
        "zip" => "98101"
    ),
);
```

I am wanting to loop over the first array for all states that I have in the $states array but I want to replace the values in the $request, (where noted), array with values from the $states array.

I am looping over the $states array by:

```
foreach ($states as $state => $details) {
    if ($request['City'] == $details['city'] AND $request['State'] == $details['abbr'] AND $request['ZipCode'] == $details['zip'] AND $request['County'] == $details['county'] AND $request['PropertyCity'] == $details['city'] AND $request['PropertyState'] == $details['abbr'] AND $request['PropertyZip'] == $details['zip']) {
        $state =  $details['state'];
        $abbr =   $details['abbr'];
        $city =   $details['city'];
        $county = $details['county'];
        $zip =    $details['zip'];
}
```

and using those variable for the $request array.

Currently I am getting a result that looks like the following when it runs through the $request array only:

```
    $current = array(
         "pe" => "2",
         "key" => "1234",
         "City" => "Sacramento",
         "State" => "California",
         "fname" => "John",
         "lname" => "Doe",
         "ZipCode" => "95632",
         "Email" => "jdoe@email.com",
         "Phone" => "2225550000",
    )
```

I need it to loop over the $request array for every state with the new values from the $states arrays and return a similar result for every state.

The result I am looking to get is:

```
$result = array(
    array(
          "pe" => $_REQUEST['number'], // 2
          "key" => "1234",
          "city" => "Sacramento",
          "state" => "California",
          "fname" => "John",
          "lname" => "Doe",
          "ZipCode" => "95632",
          "Email" => "jdoe@email.com",
          "phone" => "2225550000",
    ),
    array(
          "pe" => $_REQUEST['number'], // 2
          "key" => "1234",
          "city" => "Seattle",
          "state" => "Washington",
          "fname" => "John",
          "lname" => "Doe",
          "ZipCode" => "98101",
          "Email" => "jdoe@email.com",
          "phone" => "2225550000",
    )
);
```

So basically what's happening is that it works and values are getting replaced but it's only happening once, I need to have two arrays returned as I provided in my $result array.

Comment: can you provide an example of the expected output ?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the expected output. @naomik

Comment: Can any of you provide me with information on what I did wrong with this question. I am trying to learn and solve problems that I am having just as anybody else here is doing. Closing/downvoting questions without feedback doesn't help the OP know how to solve the issue and ask better questions in the future. I have edited my question a few times and haven't gotten any inkling that I am on the right track.

Comment: ~2 weeks later I still don't see any expected output. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for more details.

Comment: @naomik Thank you for your feedback, I do appreciate it, both times. Anyways, I have made another adjustment adding the expected result I am looking for.

Comment: kemosabe, your expected output has a syntax error – `$result = array(...)(...);` is not valid. Do you mean `$result = array(array(...), array(...));` ?

Comment: yes I did, I will fix that.

Comment: @naomik fixed the syntax error.

Comment: @naomik Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to combine your array. This solution will not fit your problem because your arrays doesn't share keys, You need something like this:

```
foreach($states as $stateName => $stateInfo) {
    if($request['City'] == $stateInfo['city']) AND $request['State'] == $stateInfo['abbr'] AND $request['ZipCode'] == $stateInfo['zip']) {
        $state   =   $details['state'];
        $abbr    =   $details['abbr'];
        $city    =   $details['city'];
        $county  =   $details['county'];
        $zip     =   $details['zip'];
    }
}
```

This code compares request info and if something match City, State, Zipcode those vars ($state, $abbr, $city, $county, $zip) will be filled.

Comment: This suggestion works in the fact that it shows me that it is looping through and checking multiple things but now I am getting a bunch of undefined index errors. Would you recommend adding $details['state'] into the $request array or just the $state variable? Any other suggestions?